# adding value and name to select box

Tags: php, jquery

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT `docid`, `fullname` FROM `doctors` ORDER BY fullname ASC";
$result = $database->query($sql) or die('cannot connect to the database');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo"<option value= ".$row['docid'].">".$row['fullname']."</option>";
}
?>
```

This is my select box which i am populating through datbase table.

```
$('.sheUpdate').click(function(){   

    var deptment = $(this).attr('dptname');
    var deptid   = $(this).attr('dptid');

    i want to make this one as SELECTED ITEM ON THE Select box  
    $("#Deptmentselectbox").prepend('<option value='+deptid+'>'+deptment+'</option>')

});
```

This is my jquery code. When i click ".sheUpdate" link i have couple of values that i am grabing using attr function. i am grabing depatment name and department value which i want to show as the SELECTED ITEM ON THE SELECT BOX

Comment: Where is your .sheUpdate class ?

Comment: What errors do you get? What happens when you debug?

Comment: `attr()` is only used for HTML attributes.

Comment: i am able to see that option as the first item on the list. but i want to show it in the selectbox instead of the "Select your department".. this is used to update the department.

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong. By default, your select box has an entry `select your dept` which you want to remove when the first element is selected. Is it so?

Comment: yes thats so correct Karan Punamiya

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to see more code to be able to properly help. What is the html code of the element with the .sheUpdate class?

Does this link element actually have attributes dptname and dptid?

What is the code you use on #Deptmentselectbox?

Comment: <td align="center"><a href="#" class="sheUpdate"  dptid=<?php echo $departmentid; ?> dptname=<?php echo $depatment; ?> time=<?php echo $time; ?> date=<?php echo $date; ?> status=<?php echo $status; ?> ><img src="../../images/Sit_related/edit.png" /></a></td>

Answer (score 0):

The code you added is working properly.
just need to set the new added element as selected.

**[please check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RnmmA/)**
Also please let me know what value you get if you write this

```
alert($(this).attr('dptname'));
alert($(this).attr('dptid'));


$('.sheUpdate').click(function(){   

    var deptment = $(this).attr('dptname');
    var deptid   = $(this).attr('dptid');   
    $("#Deptmentselectbox").prepend('<option value='+deptid+'>'+deptment+'</option>')
    $("#Deptmentselectbox").get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
    // OR $("#Deptmentselectbox").val(deptid);
});
```

Comment: i saw your fiddle. tell me how to put prepended option to as selected one instead of using like this  $("#Deptmentselectbox").prepend('<option value='+deptid+'>'+deptment+'</option>')
$("#Deptmentselectbox").val(deptment)

Comment: $('#Deptmentselectbox').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;   OR  $("#Deptmentselectbox").val(deptid)

Comment: create a JS fiddle and send a link so we can check what is wrong exactly. add some dummy data instead of taking it from server.

Comment: Add the <select> html which is missing in the first code segment

Comment: K D its Perfectly Working. Thank You So Much..i wish i could vote..my reputation is very low

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Solution Hope it Helps

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test1").click(function(){
        var data = $("#t").val();
        var data1 = $("#r").val();
        $("#try").prepend('<option value='+data+' selected="selected">'+data1+'</option>');
    });

   });
```

[Click Here For Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p3Kys/2/)

Comment: not working since the prepended item is not the SELECTED item on the select box Roger

Comment: @AhmedYaser: Updated my link and answer. Please check. and let me know if you want that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your initial select box is like this:

```
<select id="Deptmentselectbox">
    <option value=''> Select a department </option>
</select>
```

To remove the placeholder on first option selected:

```
$('.sheUpdate').click(function(){   
    var deptment = $(this).attr('dptname');
    var deptid   = $(this).attr('dptid');   
    if($("#Deptmentselectbox").val() == '')
     $("#Deptmentselectbox").html('<option value='+deptid+'>'+deptment+'</option>');
    else
     $("#Deptmentselectbox").prepend('<option value='+deptid+'>'+deptment+'</option>');
    $("#Deptmentselectbox").val(deptid);
}
```